# Simulink on MATLAB R2021a says "Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, matlab

These are the error messages when I open simulink on Matlab R2021a on my Ubuntu 20.04. I recently installed both the OS and MATLAB.

[image: error1]
[image: error2]

> SlProxy service unavailable.

and

> Error loading /usr/local/MATLAB/R2021a/bin/glnxa64/builtins/sl_main/mwlibmwsimulink_builtinimpl.so. /usr/local/MATLAB/R2021a/bin/glnxa64/builtins/sl_main/../../../../bin/glnxa64/libmwsl_prm_engine.so: undefined symbol: _Z27FcnCheckAndConvParamToFixPtPK7SLBlockP21_slDataTypeAccess_tagPKvPKclibiPv: Resource temporarily unavailable: Resource temporarily unavailable

I have searched for them online, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Additionally, when I dismiss these messages and try to create a new blank model, I get another error:

[image: error3]

> Error loading /usr/local/MATLAB/R2021a/bin/glnxa64/builtins/sl_main/mwlibmwsimulink_builtinimpl.so. /usr/local/MATLAB/R2021a/bin/glnxa64/builtins/sl_main/../../../../bin/glnxa64/libmwsl_prm_engine.so: undefined symbol: _Z27FcnCheckAndConvParamToFixPtPK7SLBlockP21_slDataTypeAccess_tagPKvPKclibiPv: No such file or directory: No such file or directory

Please advise.

Comment: MATLAB is a commercial proprietary software. Please ask in their support channel instead.

[Octave](http://octave.org) has a free and open source simulink alternative. https://wiki.octave.org/Sci_cosim However, it may not be completely compatible with simulink.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I already have asked a question on MATLAB answers, without any luck. Plus, I was suspecting this might be a permissions issue. I also already use Octave, but my needs are specific to Simulink's functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it installing an update from the notifications icon of the Matlab home page. Restarting Matlab, now Simulink works successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up doing a complete reinstall, post which it worked just fine. I assume some files were missing or corrupted, which might have potentially gotten fixed during the update.